# How can I query item wise stocks and revenue in django ORM?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-orm

```
class RevenueStockDashboardViewset(ViewSet):

    sale = InvSaleDetail.objects.filter(sale_main__sale_type='SALE')
    sale_returns = InvSaleDetail.objects.filter(sale_main__sale_type='RETURN')
    purchase = InvPurchaseDetail.objects.filter(purchase_main__purchase_type='PURCHASE')
    purchase_returns = InvPurchaseDetail.objects.filter(purchase_main__purchase_type='RETURN')

    def list(self, request):

        total_revenue = (self.sale.annotate(total=Sum('sale_main__grand_total'))
                        .aggregate(total_revenue=Sum('total'))
                        .get('total_revenue') or 0) - (self.sale_returns.annotate(total=Sum('sale_main__grand_total'))
                        .aggregate(total_revenue=Sum('total'))
                        .get('total_revenue') or 0) - (self.purchase.annotate(total=Sum('purchase_main__grand_total'))
                        .aggregate(total_revenue=Sum('total'))
                        .get('total_revenue') or 0) + (self.purchase_returns.annotate(total=Sum('purchase_main__grand_total'))
                        .aggregate(total_revenue=Sum('total'))
                        .get('total_revenue') or 0)
        
        total_stocks = (self.purchase.annotate(total=Sum('qty'))
                    .aggregate(total_stock=Sum('total'))
                    .get('total_stock') or 0) - (self.purchase_returns.annotate(total=Sum('qty'))
                    .aggregate(total_stocks=Sum('total'))
                    .get('total_stock') or 0) - (self.sale.annotate(total=Sum('qty'))
                    .aggregate(total_stock=Sum('total'))
                    .get('total_stock') or 0) - (self.sale_returns.annotate(total=Sum('qty'))
                    .aggregate(total_stock=Sum('total'))
                    .get('total_stock') or 0)

        
        return Response(        
            {
                'total_revenue': total_revenue,
                'total_stocks': total_stocks,
                # 'item_wise_stocks': items,
            }
        )
```

**Item Model:**

```
class InvItem(CreatedInfoModel):

    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        unique=True,
        help_text="Item name should be max. of 100 characters",
    )
    code = models.CharField(
        max_length=10,
        unique=True,
        blank=True,
        help_text="Item code should be max. of 10 characters",
    )
```

sale models:

```
class InvSaleDetail(CreatedInfoModel):

sale_main = models.ForeignKey(
    InvSaleMain, related_name="inv_sale_details", on_delete=models.PROTECT
)
item = models.ForeignKey(InvItem, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
item_category = models.ForeignKey(InvItemCategory, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
cost = models.DecimalField(
    max_digits=12,
    decimal_places=2,
    help_text="cost can have max value upto=9999999999.99 and default=0.0",
)
qty = models.DecimalField(
    max_digits=12,
    decimal_places=2,
    help_text="Purchase quantity can have max value upto=9999999999.99 and min_value=0.0",
)

sale_qty = models.DecimalField(
    max_digits=12,
    decimal_places=2,
    help_text="Sale quantity can be max value upto 9999999999.99",
)
```

purchase Models:

```
class InvPurchaseDetail(CreatedInfoModel):
    purchase_main = models.ForeignKey(
        InvPurchaseMain,
        related_name="purchase_details",
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
    )
    item = models.ForeignKey(InvItem, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    item_category = models.ForeignKey(InvItemCategory, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    purchase_cost = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=12,
        decimal_places=2,
        default=0.0,
        help_text="purchase_cost can be max value upto 9999999999.99 and default=0.0",
    )
    sale_cost = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=12,
        decimal_places=2,
        help_text="sale_cost can be max value upto 9999999999.99 and default=0.0",
    )
    qty = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=12,
        decimal_places=2,
        help_text="Purchase quantity can be max value upto 9999999999.99",
    )
```

I have Inventory Dashboard where I want to show the item wise revenue and item wise stocks. I have done query for total stocks and revenue but I want item wise. If you need more information. Please let me Know.

There is purchase model and sale model, the sale_main and purchase_main is basically sale and puchase info and detail is detail about items we are adding.

I want basically to fetch item wise, calculate revenue as i did and show item wise.

Comment: From which model come the `items`, could you print out the models' definitions?

Comment: ok, i updated the question description with models.